# Finding a regular-expression-like sequence of values in a Clojure vector

Tags: clojure

I am using the [libpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) library to find an full address (street, city, state, and postal code) within a news article. libpostal when given input text:

> There was an accident at 5 Main Street Boulder, CO 10566 -- which is at the corner of Wilson.

returns a vector:

```
[{:label "house", :value "there was an accident at 5"}
 {:label "road", :value "main street"} 
 {:label "city", :value "boulder"}
 {:label "state", :value "co"}
 {:label "postcode", :value "10566"}
 {:label "road", :value "which is at the corner of wilson."}
```

I am wondering if there is a clever way in Clojure to extract a sequence where the `:label` values occur in a sequence:

```
[road unit? level? po_box? city state postcode? country?]
```

where `?` represents an optional value in the match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with [clojure.spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec). First define some specs that match your maps' `:label` values:

```
(defn has-label? [m label] (= label (:label m)))
(s/def ::city #(has-label? % "city"))
(s/def ::postcode #(has-label? % "postcode"))
(s/def ::state #(has-label? % "state"))
(s/def ::house #(has-label? % "house"))
(s/def ::road #(has-label? % "road"))
```

Then define a [regex spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_sequences) e.g. `s/cat` + `s/?`:

```
(s/def ::valid-seq
  (s/cat :road ::road
         :city (s/? ::city) ;; ? = zero or once
         :state ::state
         :zip (s/? ::postcode)))
```

Now you can `conform` or `valid?`-ate your sequences:

```
(s/conform ::valid-seq [{:label "road" :value "Damen"}
                        {:label "city" :value "Chicago"}
                        {:label "state" :value "IL"}])
=>
{:road {:label "road", :value "Damen"},
 :city {:label "city", :value "Chicago"},
 :state {:label "state", :value "IL"}}
;; this is also valid, missing an optional value in the middle
(s/conform ::valid-seq [{:label "road" :value "Damen"}
                        {:label "state" :value "IL"}
                        {:label "postcode" :value "60622"}])
=>
{:road {:label "road", :value "Damen"},
 :state {:label "state", :value "IL"},
 :zip {:label "postcode", :value "60622"}}
```

Comment: I really like this approach. As far as skipping through the text prior to the address, would you recommend just looping through the vector with `rest` until either it is valid or end is reached?

Comment: @frank if your inputs might have invalid prefixes then I suppose they could also have invalid suffixes. If "brute force" isn't too costly it's a fine starting point. You could also try adding wildcard prefix/suffix into your spec e.g. `(s/cat :prefix (s/* map?) ... :suffix (s/* map?))` but I wouldn't expect great performance for large inputs. For large inputs you could be better off writing your own state machine/parser.